# How to setup two interfaces on one NAS to isolate WAN and maximize LAN traffic speed?

Tags: networking, lan, wan

How should I setup my NAS network settings to isolate WAN and LAN traffic on each physical interfaces (1 and 2) to maximize LAN traffic speed? Or does another option exist to achieve this result without making changes on LAN clients?

I have next home network setup - router with WAN port to ISP and some LAN ports, linux-based NAS with two ports and some PC.

```
      ┌────────┐
      │  ISP   │
      └─┬──────┘
        │
        │ WAN port
      ┌─┴──────┐
      │ Router │
      └┬┬──────┴┐
       ││LAN ports
       ││       │
     1 ││2      │
┌──────┴┴┐      ├──────┐
│  NAS   │      │  PC  │
└────────┘      └──────┘
```

My router setup out-of-box - DHCP for LAN and dynamic IP for LAN connections. And its relativity old - without link aggregation (IEEE 802.3ad) support.
Current NAS network settings for both interfaces are **mode-1 (active-backup)** (both connected, one active used) at bond.

Comment: What do you mean by "maximize LAN traffic speed", what the current problem? And which traffic exactly to you want to isolate? Do you already use both NAS ports? What's the current network configuration?

Comment: The dual link between NAS and router doesn't seem to serve any purpose. Also, we have no idea where there's a bottleneck in your setup. What performance do you expect and what are you getting?  Please add sufficient detail to your question on where your problem is and what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: My current problem - NAS has only one active connection to router (one bond), part of it occupied by NAS itself (Internet-backup from NAS) and remains used by LAN clients.  And it seems good idea to have two independent channel to achieve full speed at LAN "part" any time, without any affection from WAN-activity.

Comment: I seems I may use Balance-tlb (Mode 5) for bond, but its mode use both connection for Tx regardless destination and provide no guaranties for LAN users.

Comment: As I know it should be used VLAN for these purposes, but for SOHO routers it's not possible.

Comment: First of all: having two ports on the NAS doesn't necessarly mean that you can use both ports at full speed at the same time so even if your solution can be implemented you might not get your desired results. You have to check that first. I updated my answer with a third option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NAS has only one active connection to router (one bond), part of it occupied by NAS itself (Internet-backup from NAS) and remains used by LAN clients. And it seems good idea to have two independent channel to achieve full speed at LAN "part" any time, without any affection from WAN-activity.

That is actually clearer than your question.

To separate traffic flows towards WAN and within LAN - provided your NAS's storage can keep up - you need to set up two different IP addresses in LAN with both interfaces marked active. Naturally, this is only useful when your physical links get saturated during use.

The first, WAN-facing address is the one that you use for the default gateway/route. It's also the address that you forward to from your router if you're exposing services.

The second, LAN-facing address is the one that you use to access NAS resources locally. If you've got proper DNS that's what you resolve the NAS's host name to. If there's no proper DNS you probably can't rely on broadcast resolution, so you should put the NAS IP and host name in the *hosts* file on your local PCs.

Using layer-2 link aggregation requires your router (or intermediate managed switch) to support LAG (LACP or static). For a consumer router that's unlikely. Also, LAG uses an address hash for traffic distribution on the physical links, so it's somewhat random and a clean separation of your flows somewhat unlikely.

Of course, setting up separate IP subnets and VLANs for WAN-side and LAN-side traffic would the clean way, but your router would need to be able to separate its network-layer LAN interfaces for that - most consumer routers only use a single LAN-side interface and integrate a switch for multiple interfaces. Using dedicated IP addresses as described above should do the trick as well.

Comment: "WAN-facing address is the one that you use for the default gateway/route." If I'm not mistaken, that only works if you can set up static routes on the NAS.

Comment: @Albin Correct - most NASes with multiple NICs that I've seen allow setting a specific interface for the default route though.

Comment: Then, as far as I see it, this is essentially the same answer I already posted a day earlier.

Comment: if you essentially "repost" my answer - while I don't mean to blame you, I would really appreciate a reference or an upvote. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to achive, usually you should be allset by assigning different IPs to the different ports on the NAS. So if you want to access the NAS via port 1 you use it's assigned IP adress and if you want to go via port 2 you use it's IP adress.

If the NAS "initiates" the connection to the device (e.g. to a backup server on the internet) you need to specify static routes on the NAS itself. E.g. traffic to 192.168.1.0/24 (your LAN) goes through port 1 and everything else goes through port 2.

Another option would be, if your router has the option for a second network e.g. a guest network: setup one of the ports for the guest network (including a default gateway) and the other port for your LAN (without a default gateway). If your router doesn't have a guest network you can use a second router to achive the same goal (note that you can not use 2 DHCP servers in the same LAN, you will need to setup the second and the port on your NAS router manually).